# How to make dependent combo boxes work correctly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, combobox

I have two combo boxes "Year" & "Amount" on the top of them I do get values for user info, because there are text boxes when called with user ID text boxes fill up with correct data.

The two combo boxes are also filled with correct data but I have to manually select year and the amount corresponding to it.

I need help in when I call the data "Year" & "Amount" should appear visible in the combo box. When I select a Year then the Amount should change accordingly. Last but not the least my reset is not clearing the combo boxes.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace dss
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=JG_Test;Integrated Security=True");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            cmbYear.Items.Clear();
            string sql = "";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            try
            {
                sql += "SELECT m.MemberId, m.Name, m.Address, m.Cellular, m.Email, p.PaymentId, p.Year, p.Amount from Members as m";
                sql += " INNER JOIN Payments as p ON m.MemberId = p.MemberId";
                sql += " WHERE m.MemberId = '" + tbID.Text + "' ORDER BY p.Year ASC";

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                if(dt.Rows.Count >0)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i<=dt.Rows.Count -1;i++)
                    {
                        tbID.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MemberId"].ToString();
                        tbName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                        tbCellular.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Cellular"].ToString();
                        tbEmail.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString();
                        tbAddress.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();

                        cmbAmount.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Amount"].ToString());
                        cmbYear.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Year"].ToString());

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        //This part displaying og the existing data from all the fileds corrssponding within the database//
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                con.Open();

                string Sql = "INSERT INTO Members ( MemberId, Name, Cellular, Email, Address ) VALUES " + " (@Id, @name, @cell, @email, @address)";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con))

                {
                    cmd.CommandText = Sql;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", tbID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", tbName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cell", tbCellular.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", tbCellular.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", tbAddress.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Sql = "INSERT INTO Payments ( MemberId, [Year], [Amount] ) VALUES " + " (@Id, Amount, Year)";

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.CommandText = Sql;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", tbID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", cmbYear.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", cmbAmount.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Data Added");

                    tbID.Clear(); tbName.Clear(); tbCellular.Clear(); tbEmail.Clear(); tbAddress.Clear(); cmbYear.Items.Clear(); cmbAmount.Items.Clear();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        //This part represents adding of  new input data from all the fileds into the database//
        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                string Sql = "UPDATE Members SET MemberId = '" + tbID.Text + "', Name = '" + tbName.Text + "', Cellular = '" + tbCellular.Text + "', Email = '" + tbEmail.Text + "', Address = '" + tbAddress.Text + "' WHERE MemberId = '" + tbID.Text + "' ";
                cmd.CommandText = Sql;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                Sql = "UPDATE Payments SET MemberId = '" + tbID.Text + "', Year = '" + cmbYear.Text + "', Amount = '" + cmbAmount.Text + "' WHERE MemberId = '" + tbID.Text + "' ";
                cmd.CommandText = Sql;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
                tbID.Clear(); tbName.Clear(); tbAddress.Clear(); tbCellular.Clear(); tbEmail.Clear(); cmbYear.Items.Clear(); cmbAmount.Items.Clear();

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
            }
        }

        //This part represents deleteing of input data from all the fileds into the database//
        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                string Sql = "DELETE FROM Members WHERE MemberId = '" + tbID.Text + "' ";
                cmd.CommandText = Sql;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                Sql = "DELETE  FROM Payments WHERE MemberId = '" + tbID.Text + "' ";
                cmd.CommandText = Sql;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tbID.Clear(); tbName.Clear(); tbAddress.Clear(); tbCellular.Clear(); tbEmail.Clear(); cmbYear.Items.Clear(); cmbAmount.Items.Clear();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted");

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
            }

        }

        //This part represents clearing of input data from all the fileds//
        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbID.Clear(); tbName.Clear(); tbAddress.Clear(); tbCellular.Clear(); tbEmail.Clear(); cmbYear.Items.Clear(); cmbAmount.Items.Clear();
        }

        //This part represents shuting down the application//
        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes you would, because there is no corrilation between the two combo boxes and there shouldnt be normally..   Your reset does look like it should clear the combo boxes.. are you sure the code is running?

Comment: Affirmative !!! exactly the code I have nothing else !!!

Comment: did you step through it? is it just the text showing that isnt going? or all the items staying?

Comment: well as I mentioned in my initial comment, it is getting all the correct data, but just the year & amount stay hidden and I have to click the side arrow pointing down to toggle to see the years and also the amount.

Comment: Yes you would - thats how combo boxes work - and if your data was say year "1972" value "200" and year "2016" and value "9237" you could select 1972 and 9237 .. because they are totally unrelated..

Comment: I agree but that what I am trying to find out they should appear visable firstly, 2nd when I select "2016" it should automatically show "300" which is not happening the automating of functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112792/discussion-between-jg7000-and-bugfinder).

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to simplify things a bit. Treat the personal data and the finance data as 2 parts.

Firstly, request the personal data - keep it simple

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string sql = "SELECT MemberId, Name, Address, Cellular, Email FROM Members WHERE MemberId = @Id";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("myconnectionstring");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.Int).Value = tbID.Text;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

try
{
    con.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
con.Close();
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}

tbID.Text = dt.Rows[0]["MemberId"].ToString();
tbName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
tbCellular.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Cellular"].ToString();
tbEmail.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
tbAddress.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
}
```

Once thats done, move on to second part - the years/amounts combo (which is almost identical code)

```
string sql = "SELECT Year, Amount FROM Payments WHERE MemberId = @Id"

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("myconnectionstring");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.Int).Value = tbID.Text;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

try
{
    con.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
con.Close();
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}

cmbYear.DataSource = dt;
cmbYear.DisplayMember = "Year";
cmbYear.ValueMember = "Amount";
```

And finally, tell the textbox what it needs to read by using

```
private void cmbYear_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    amountTxt.Text = cmbYear.SelectedValue.ToString();

}
```

in the combobox's `SelectionChangeCommitted` event

And that should have you sorted!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I actually added three lines of code in my existing solution. I did get the desired functionality, but a few small "glitches" like I get the "Year" to appear correctly but the "Amount" dont appear unless I choose the second "Year" value and then I can see both if I toggel. Lastly the "clear" function" for "Amount" dont work.

Comment: are you still using a combobox to display amount? As you stated before, you only have a single value to display for each year, thus a combobox would be the wrong control. Set the selected index property for the year combobox to -1 so your amount will only show when a year has been clicked

Comment: Yes! But just right now I changed it to "text box" and the result is when I choose the "year" instead of "amount" I get "year" in the "amount" text box. This is confusing.

Comment: assuming you used the solution i provided, make sure you have set the valuemember property to be the amount eg `combobox.ValueMember = "Amount"` and make sure you are sending the selectedvalue, NOT selectedtext

Comment: is it possible if you can join me in a live session to see whats going on, it would save a lot of time and thinking, I am sure we are near a breakthrough, very simple yet so complicated.

Comment: sure. I'll log into the chat at ~1600 UK time so we can arrange it.